# Remove first index in a char*[]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

In C I want a function like this:

```
bool RemoveFirstIndex(char* inArray[])
```

which goes in and takes out the very first element in that array.

e.g.

```
inArray = "Hello\o", "How\o", "Are\o"
RemoveFirstIndex(inArray)
inArray = "How\o", "Are\o"
```

Not sure how to go about it.

I get the idea that I would have to create a new array of inSize - 1, and just fill it with everything except index 0.
But if I do that, does the function need to return a new char*[]? Isnt that a bit wasteful?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, he asked about C, so I provided a C answer for him.

Comment: Its not possible to convert `char* inArray[3]` to `char* inArray[2]` they are incompatible. This is what your example indicated your attempting to do.

Comment: In C, arrays cannot be resized; you cannot turn a 3-element array into a 2-element array or vice-versa.  If you *really* need a resizable container for your data, look into implementing a list structure (or switching to C++ and using STL containers like `vector`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why remove the first element or create a new array?

Just can just increment your pointer so it points to the next item in the array.

```
char **newArray = inArray + 1;
```

`newArray` is valid as long as `inArray` is.

Comment: +1.  Just beat me too it.  The only issue with this approach is making sure to only free the first array, and not the newArray.

Comment: @0x69: Did you look at the code?  He is not modifying the array, he is creating a new pointer that points to one element past the beginning of said array.  That is perfectly valid.

Comment: Char*'s have always confused me, especially char**. Or char*[]. Or char[][]. This makes perfect sense for a solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic memory management and just shrink that array:

```
// create the array
size_t arrsize = 10;
char **arr = malloc(arrsize * sizeof(*arr));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(/* whatever the length of the string (incl. NUL) is */);

// then use it like this:
RemoveFirstIndex(arr, &arrsize);

bool RemoveFirstIndex(char **inArray, size_t *arr_len)
{
    if (*arr_len == 0 || inArray == NULL)
        return false;

    free(inArray[0]);
    int i;
    *arr_len--;
    for (i = 0; i < *arr_len; i++)
        inArray[i] = inArray[i + 1];

    inArray = realloc(inArray, sizeof(*inArray) * (*arr_len));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void RemoveFirstIndex(std::vector<std::string> &inArray) {
    if (!inArray.empty())
        inArray.erase(inArray.begin());
}

std::vector<std::string> array = {"Hello", "How", "Are"};
RemoveFirstIndex(inArray)
// array now contains {"How", "Are"}
```

You shouldn't want to use an array of char pointers, but if you do you need to indicate its size and a way for the function to indicate the new size afterward.

```
size_t RemoveFirstIndex(char **inArray, size_t n) {
    if (n==0)
       return n;

    std::rotate(inArray,inArray+1,inArray+n);
    // raw pointers indicate we don't own these resources
    //   so we don't need to deallocate anything...
    return n-1;
}

char *array[] = {"Hello", "How", "Are"};
size_t size = sizeof array/sizeof *array;
for (size_t i=0;i<size;++i)
    std::cout << array[i] << '\n';

size = RemoveFirstIndex(array,size);
for (size_t i=0;i<size;++i)
    std::cout << array[i] << '\n';
```